# Is there a way to get country data from Webalizer?

Tags: export, report, countries, webalizer

I'm trying to export the data from Webalizer's reports, but i have a problem when it comes to the data of each country.

Webalizer generates an image containing a graph of countries statistics, but I have not been able to find any file where i can find this data besides that image.

Does Webalizer saves this data anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, webalizer data can be found here: `/home/youruser/domains/example.com/stats/` if you're using a centos server with directadmin, Browse your folders to find the location on your system as it can be somewhere else on your machine depending on your configuration. [image]

Comment: Yes, i know about this folder.

Comment: The problem is, as far as i understand it, in the file webalizer,current the ip of the users is stored, among other data, and each month (depending on the configuration) webalizer gets the geolocation of the ips and creates an html file showing the statistics and graph images.

Unfortunately, only the top x countries are shown in these files. The full country statistics are never stored anywhere, or at least i cound not find a way to get them.

Comment: Do you have a file called: webalizer.conf ? (you could try SSH, enter `whereis webalizer.conf` If found, please read contents of these files)  Did you read [link](http://www.webalizer.org/webalizer.1.html) if yes what did you try? I don't remember but somewhere you can edit/change the number of top countries and more. I'll check my configuration files and try to find the lines you need..